# Iconos que activan y desactivan contenido

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// ocultar el contenido
jQuery('#mostrar').hide();
jQuery('.botoncillo').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();jQuery("#mostrar").slideToggle();
jQuery('.botoncillo').toggleClass('opened closed');
});
});
</script>
```

Funciona correctamente al aplicarle sobre un icono o botón la clase **botoncillo** y el identificador **mostrar** al contenedor que quiero mostrar/ocultar.

Al no entender mucho de JavaScript, formulo lo siguiente.
Quisiera tener tres contenidos por ejemplo que se oculten/muestren de manera independiente según pulse tres iconos/botones.
Esto sería facil triplicando el código y cambiando las clases y los identificadores pero mi nivel pésimo de javascript no me deja hacer que un contenido que esté abierto, y cuando pulse otro botón para abrir otro contenido este se cierre y no queden dos contenidos abiertos.

Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda. Muchas Gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Estaría bien que pusieses tu código `HTML` para ver que estructura usas. De todas las maneras, he intentado recrearlo. Aquí tienes mi código, esta comentado para que lo entiendas.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  //por cada botoncillo que haga lo siguiente
  jQuery('.botoncillo').each(function () {
      //ocultamos el contenido que se muestra o se oculta
      jQuery(this).next().hide();
      //al darle el click hacemos lo siguiente:
      jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          //quitamos previamente todas las clases asignadas al boton
          //(nos hace falta para ocultar todos los contenidores innecesarios)
          jQuery('.botoncillo').each(function () {
              jQuery(this).removeClass('opened closed');
          });

          //mostramos/ocultamos el contenido
          jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
          jQuery(this).toggleClass('opened closed');

          //ocultamos TODOS los contenidores donde el boton no tenga la clase asignada
          jQuery('.botoncillo').next().each(function () {
              if (!jQuery(this).prev().hasClass('opened closed')) {
                  jQuery(this).hide("slow");
              }
          });
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="botoncillo">
        Mostrar/Ocultar
    </div>
    <div>
        Contenido que se muestra o se oculta
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="botoncillo">
        Mostrar/Ocultar
    </div>
    <div>
        Contenido que se muestra o se oculta
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="botoncillo">
        Mostrar/Ocultar
    </div>
    <div>
        Contenido que se muestra o se oculta
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="botoncillo">
        Mostrar/Ocultar
    </div>
    <div>
        Contenido que se muestra o se oculta
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="botoncillo">
        Mostrar/Ocultar
    </div>
    <div>
        Contenido que se muestra o se oculta
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="botoncillo">
        Mostrar/Ocultar
    </div>
    <div>
        Contenido que se muestra o se oculta
    </div>
</div>
```

El código esta hecho de tal manera que sea lo mas automático posible, puede ser que no sea lo correcto para tu estructura, pero no uso `ids` porque usarlas me limitaría mucho.

Espero que te sirva.